# Passing JRBeancollection datasourse to master report and subreport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I want to pass the JRBeancollection datadourse to main report and from main report to subreport.. I have included this subreport in summary section of master report..
please mention the steps i want to do in ireport including the inbuld parameters how to set.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have done it.

Actually  datasource was not going in subreport. So I have changed the property of when no data to all sections, no data...

Then I have passed the collection variable where I have fetched the subreport records.

By using   `parameters.put("shape_data_all", allShape_Caliberation);`

Then I have created a parameter in main report. And changed its class to `java.Util.Collection`.

Then in subreport property, `connection type=`   Use a datasource expression

Data Source Expression    `new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{shape_data_all})`

Then added the fields in the subreport same as I am having the bean properties.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try this:

```
<subreport>
    <reportElement x="261" y="25" width="200" height="100"/>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Of course you have to use the "subreportExpression" as you are doing in your report, this is just a sample, the useful line for your problem is where the "dataSourceExpression" is placed.