# JasperReports: Passing lists via parameter map & detail records getting printed on a new page per record

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to create a report with 2 sub-reports for new and used vehicles.

I have defined a vehicle bean as per the JavaBeans specification. I was thinking of using a parameter map to pass this data to the sub report via the main report as was described at [Passing JRBeancollection datasourse to master report and subreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426174/passing-jrbeancollection-datasourse-to-master-report-and-subreport) post.

Steps I took so far are as follows:

***The first step*** - *Passing collection as parameter*

```java
Map<String, Object> jasperParameter = new HashMap<String, Object>();
jasperParameter.put("new_Vehicles", createNewVehicles()); //returns a collection of vehicles.
```

***The second step*** - *Creating a parameter, `new_Vehicles` in my main report and set it as `Collection` data type*

***The third step*** - *Creating a data source expression for the sub-report as 
`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{new_Vehicles})`*

***The fourth step*** - *Creating a field (just to get this working before I add more fields), `vehicleId` in the sub report.*

Question/Issues I am having and would appreciate any help is:
a) When I compile it gives me an error message that the above mentioned data source cannot be resolved to a type. What am I doing incorrectly?

Ok, so I think I might have gone past the exception by adding "new" in front of the data expression, `new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{new_Vehicles})`.

But, now if there are two new vehicles that I add to the list its printing in two pages, basically one page per element in the list. My column headers are in the ***Column Header*** band and my fields are in the ***Detail*** band.

Any suggestions on how I can prevent it from putting each element in the list on a different page?

Comment: Did you delete your bands that you're not using? Try to delete them and adjust your detail band to the height of your fields. Just a guess

Comment: Thanks a lot Vyccus, that worked. I did not have other bands to begin with but i changed the height of the detail band to match the height of the fields and it works. Thanks again!

Comment: Your're welcome. I'll put this as an answer to be voted for you as the chosen one, I'm new here and don't know if it's the right thing, but seems to be better for the others who might have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete your unused bands and/or adjust the detail band to the same height as your fields.

Comment: Sure man, i have updated the post header so it is more relevant. Regards.